# Installation of virt-manager while yum update and yum install rhvm does not work

Tags: kvm-virtualization, xen, qemu, virt-manager

I have downloaded RHEV-H 4.2 https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-virtualization#getstarted (RHVirtualization 4.2 Host and Manager iso). I uploaded the image and installed on an HP G9 server baremetal.

I found I dont have a WAN/net connectivity later on HPG9 server. How can I still install virt-manager on that machine??

Is it like virt-manager has to be in the same machine HP G9 ?

Can virt-manager be installed in a VM guest in my desktop that can help manage the hypervisor installed in HP G9 server?

Or should I download some virt-manager 4.2 pkgs on my laptop, upload it to HP G9 server and then start virt-manager installation??

Please answer what should be the best and feasible approach...

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using RHEV interface to manage this node? That's what was installed, after all.

Comment: RHV doesn't use virt-manager. For your first proof of concept installation I recommend you do the self-hosted engine installation shown on that page you linked to.